# ado.net CommandBehavior.KeyInfo / getSchema method

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, schema, datareader

Work on C# asp.net vs2008. with **Reader** = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo) i try to get foreign keys , is there a way to get it ? 
if i write

```
     string sql = string.Format("Select * from {0}", tableName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

    DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Then on isKey=true set for primary key.I want to get foreign key from this command.Is there any way to get it.
If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the administrative Priviliges. You can get the result from the below query.

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
Where FK.TABLE_NAME = YourtableName
```

You can use the below code in your code behind

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Connection String");
            con.Open();

            string str = "SELECT ";
            str+= " K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,";
            str+= " FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,";
            str+= " PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,";
            str+= " PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,";
            str+= " Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME";
            str+= " FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C";
            str+= " INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME";
            str+= " INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME";

            str+= " INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME";
            str+= " INNER JOIN (";
            str+= " SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME";
            str+= " FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1";
            str+= " INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME";
            str+= " WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'";
            str+= " ) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME";
            str+= " Where FK.TABLE_NAME = 'f'";

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**ADO.NET does not currently return foreign key information from a data source. CommandBehavior.KeyInfo refers to primary key information only.**

**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107**

**Use this::**

**select

fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME,fk.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, cn.TABLE_NAME,cn.COLUMN_NAME

from

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS as fk

join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as pk

on

pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME=fk.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME

join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as cn

on cn.CONSTRAINT_NAME=fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

where cn.TABLE_NAME='tablename'**